# An option in the dropdown is not reading by webdriver

Tags: java, selenium-webdriver

Scenario: compares old month and new Month and if both are not equal it downloads the new month's report.

here is the site link: http://www.depreportingservices.state.pa.us/ReportServer/Pages/ReportViewer.aspx?%2fOil_Gas%2fOil_Gas_Well_Historical_Production_Report

It reads All, and ignores All option the reads Jan 2016 and downloads report and directly skipping to Nov instead of downloading Dec report. Static old month i am taking from a txt file that is: Oct 2015

Below is the code:

```
WebElement selectElement = driver.findElement(By.id("ReportViewerControl_ctl04_ctl03_ddValue"));
             //Getting the count of the values in the drop down list 
              Select listBox = new Select(selectElement);
              int size1 = listBox.getOptions().size();
              //prints the size to the console
              System.out.println("Total no. of months in the drop down is:"+ size1);

          System.out.println("The old month is: " + oldMonth);
          //String newMonth ="";
          //listBox.selectByIndex(3);
          String newMonth ;


              for (int i = 1; i < size1; i++) {
                  WebElement mSelectElement = driver.findElement(By.xpath(".//*[@id='ReportViewerControl_ctl04_ctl03_ddValue']"));
                  List<WebElement> optionsList = mSelectElement.findElements(By.tagName("option"));
              WebElement element = optionsList.get(i);
              newMonth = element.getText();

              //Message that prints the new month
              System.out.println("The new month is:"+newMonth);

          /*Condition to check if the New month is equal to Old month, if it is not equal then proceeds
           * to download that particular month data or else breaks the loop
           */
              if (!oldMonth.equals("All") & !newMonth.equals("All")) {
          if (oldMonth.equals(newMonth)) {
              System.out.println("No new months are available to download");
               Wait(10000);
              driver.close();
              break;
          }//else if (i==1 || (oldMonth.equals(newMonth))) {
          //else if (i==1 & !(oldMonth.equals(newMonth))) {
         else if (!(oldMonth.equals(newMonth))) {   
              download report

}
```

it has to go back to for loop

Comment: please confirm from where are you comparing old month to new month

Comment: i told right statically i set up one txt file= oct 2015 will be the month, from txt file i will compare the string. The newmonth will be starting from "All" in the selection. All !=oct 2015, Jan !=oct 2015 etc...

Answer (score 0):

```
// your given url
        driver.get("http://www.depreportingservices.state.pa.us/ReportServer/Pages/ReportViewer.aspx?%2fOil_Gas%2fOil_Gas_Well_Historical_Production_Report");
        // take everything inside the dd inside the list
        List<WebElement> allOptions = driver.findElements(By.xpath("//*[@id='ReportViewerControl_ctl04_ctl03_ddValue']/option"));
        System.out.println("Size is : " + allOptions.size());

        String oldMonth = "Dec 2015 (Unconventional wells)"; // old value that will come form a .txt file
        for(int i=0;i<allOptions.size();i++){
            System.out.println("Values inside the REPORTING PERIOD  : " + allOptions.get(i).getText());
// now compare old month value with drop down value if matches then perform your action or in your case if not matches then perform your action
// if(!allOptions.get(i).getText().equals(oldMonth))

  if(allOptions.get(i).getText().equals(oldMonth)){
      // perform any action
     allOptions.get(i).click(); // selecting value in the dd
            driver.findElement(By.id("ReportViewerControl_ctl04_ctl00")).click(); //clicking on view report
                        break;
                    }
                }
```

update : your if logic to this logic

```
 // Condition to check if the New month is equal to Old month, if it is not equal then proceeds
 // to download that particular month data or else breaks the loop

             if(!oldMonth.equals(newMonth)){
                 System.out.println(newMonth +"perform your action");
                 // download particular month data
             }else{
                 System.out.println("newMonth matches with oldMonth");
                 break;
             }
```

Comment: no my problem is after reading jan, it should read Dec but skipping to Nov. That is the issue. I don't want to give old month as Dec.